# cant install windows 7 or 8.1 . The selected disk is of the GPT partition style

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, backup, gpt

I can't install Windows 7 or Windows 8.1 so that I won't lose my data on 2nd disk.

[image: http://im51.gulfup.com/BAomx6.jpg]

Any way to back up the data? or install Windows without formating 2nd disk?

Comment: Its nearly impossible to convert a GPT disk to MBR without data loss, and even if you attempt to do it ( it is possible ) a require step is to backup your data.  So often its easier to just backup your data, format the drive, and use a MBR partition instead.  Of course Windows 7 supports GPT and UEFI so just installing Windows 7 in UEFI mode is easier.

Comment: sry but idk how to do it "installing Windows 7 in UEFI mode" ,, and i want to back up data then format drive,  but how?

Comment: In your previous question you seem to indicate you know how to backup your data.

Comment: You haven't stated which you are using, but 32-bit versions of Windows 7 and 8 do *NOT* support booting from GPT.  What's the info given under "Show Details"?

Comment: Several partitioning tools can convert from MBR to GPT or from GPT to MBR without data loss. The one with which I'm most familiar is my own [GPT fdisk (`gdisk`),](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/) which will probably convert the shown disk without problems. See [the `gdisk` documentation on this topic](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/mbr2gpt.html#gpt2mbr) for details. That said, if you're booting some other OS from the disk, *do not convert the partition table type,* since that OS will then fail to boot. Post more details for better advice.

Answer (score -1):

This is doable, just not with Windows tools but the Hiren BootCD and UltimateBootCD iterations have numerous tools to do exactly this.

Unsure if LinuX GPart does since I've used it for resize operations,

I'd suggest researching Gpart (Gparted)s ability to do this since it's a fairly mature and reliable method.
If not, and from the comfort of a more Windows set of menus, download Hirens as long as it includes a copy of Paragon "pro".

Be advised, Hirens is more of a licentious version of the Ultimate Boot CD since Hirens has been criticized but they've taken notice and corrected many complaints of including fully featured license software that a person could abuse w/o paying for.
They've managed to establish relationships, get legal permission, special better feature time codes and other methods to present high functioning tools you'd normally pay for but conditionally.

Depending on where your downloading Hirens from, such as from work with a content filtering proxy, the proxy may not be aware of Hiren's new conditions and just abject ban your attempts to acquire the ISO while creeeping you closer towards the no fly list.

Paragon inside Hirens can revert GPT drives, as always, you're well advised to back up the irreplaceable data whenever adjusting partition tables and that is a serious advisory instead of just "back up your registry before using regedit" warning.

Paragon and various tools can backup your file table but you're not versed in arcane partition management topics and this can be precarious if munged.